# Difference of muti-variable function values and single-variable definite integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I am self-studing a book about calculus of variations. I faced a statement that looks natural, but I do not see how to prove it and why we need additional assumptions about $F$. The section is about computation of second variation. So, if we have

$F=F(z,u,x):\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $F_z, F_u, F_{zz},F_{zu},F_{uu}$ all exists and continuous, then $$F(z+v,u+h,x)-F(z,u,x) = \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt}F(z+tv, u+th,x)\,dt.$$

Please help me to understand the following:

1. How to prove this.
2. Why are assumptions about $F$ are necessary.

**Update:**

I have an idea on how to approach #1. If we fix $z, u, x, v, h$ and consider function $F^*=F^*(t)=F(z+tv, u+th,x)$. Clearly, $F^*:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and we apply Newton-Leibniz formula. However, to apply that formula, we must prove that $F^*$ is continuous (and thus integrable). Why is it continuous?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why the assumptions on the second derivatives are necessary either. Continuity of the partial derivatives ensures that $F$ is differentiable, hence $g(t) = F(z+tv, u+th, x)$ as the composition of differentiable functions is differentiable and its derivative is given by the chain rule. This derivative is continuous since it is a product of continuous functions. I'm not sure where the existence and continuity of the second derivatives comes in.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just copy you answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, I don't see why the conditions on the second derivative are necessary either.

As you point out in your "update" section, the crux of the problem is to prove that the one-dimension function
$$g(t): t\mapsto F(z+tv, u+th, x)$$
is continuously differentiable. Since the partial derivatives of $F$ exist and are continuous, $F$ is differentiable; $g$ is thus the composition of differentiable functions and so is differentiable. Its derivative is given by the chain rule,
$$g'(t) = F_z(z+tv, u+th,x) v + F_u(z+tv, u+th, x) h$$
and since $g'$ is the product and sum of continuous function, it is continuous.